# This version of the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support these types of projects

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

After updating an existing project to ASP.NET Core 1.1 and Entity Framework Core 1.1 using this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1)
I tried to execute "Add-Migration MigrationName" in Package Management Console but got an error:

> Startup project 'src\ProjectName' is an ASP.NET Core or .NET Core
>   project for Visual Studio 2015. This version of the Entity Framework
>   Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support these types of
>   projects.

I am using VS 2015 Update 3.
Project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "CoursesManagement.DAL": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

global.json

```
{
  "projects": [ "src" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/07/announcing-net-core-tools-1-0/#user-content-migrating-projectjson-projects-to-csproj) blog,

> We’re now encouraging everyone to migrate to MSBuild and csproj from project.json. As I stated above, we will not be supporting any of the new .NET Core tools in Visual Studio 2015. We also won’t be updating the Visual Studio 2015 project.json-based tools.

You are using `EFCore.Tools` package version `1.1.0` which doesn't support project.json. The tooling for project.json never reached RTM. The suitable preview version to use for EF Core 1.1 packages is `EFCore.Tools` `1.1.0-preview4-final`.

Also as mentioned in other answers, if you want to use powershell commands then you need to install `EFCore.Tools` package but if you want `dotnet ef` then you need to install `EFCore.Tools.DotNet` (version `1.1.0-preview3-final` since preview4-final had minor issue).

As noted above, there will not be any updates to project.json-based tools. You can still use above preview package though best option would be to migrate to VS2017 csproj when you can.

Answer (score 5):

As per official ASP.NET Core team announcement (see [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/208)) the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package was split into `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet`.

You need to reference the later one, if you want to continue to use the `dotnet ef` commands. If you only want to use the old powershell styled commands (`Database-Update`, `Add-Migration`, etc.) the old package should be sufficient.

When referencing ``` Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet``there is no need to also reference ``Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools ```.

[Quote by Rowan Miller](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/208)

> If you are using ASP.NET Core, then you need to update the tools
>   section of project.json to use the new
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet package (rather than the
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package).
>
> ```
> "tools": {
>   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview3-final" 
> },
> ```
>
> As the design of .NET CLI Tools has
>   progressed, it has become necessary for us to separate the dotnet ef
>   tools into this separate package. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
>   is still used for Package Manager Console commands.

Now that EF Core is released it should be of course

```
 "tools": {
   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0" 
 },
```

Also please note, that the tools do not share the version with the EF itself. The latest version of the tools is still 1.0.0 for Tools.DotNet(see [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet/)) and 1.1.0 for Tools (see [Nuget again](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/)).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the commads are different in .NET Core and EF Core.

Try

```
dotnet ef migrations add MigrationName
```

and

```
dotnet ef database update
```

[Here are the dotnet cli commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)