# Scaffold-DbContext dont work with dotnet core web application project

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, scaffolding

I'm trying to make a .net core web app with database first approach, i added a Class Library (.Net Core) project to my solution in witch i add an 'Entities' folder that will contain my Entities after Scaffolding from SSMS. I used this command in the Package Manager Console : `Scaffold-DbContext "Server=DESKTOP-5B6ICSS\EBP;Database=Paie;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Entities` , but nothing works and i get this error message : `Startup project 'src\02-Model\Paie01.Model' is an ASP.NET Core or .NET Core project for Visual Studio 2015. This version of the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support these types of projects.`

Comment: This question is probably a dublicate. Provide more details about your environment (dotnet, packages, VS versions) to determine it: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068552/this-version-of-the-entity-framework-core-package-manager-console-tools-doesnt