# Add-Migration issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've got issue with my ASP.NET Core Application. I wanted to add Database using Entity Framework but Visual Studio 2015 shows an below error.

Could you please check my files and let me know what's wrong with my application? Thank you a lot in advance.

> Startup project 'src\Store' is an ASP.NET Core or .NET Core project
>   for Visual Studio 2015. This version of the Entity Framework Core
>   Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support these types of projects.

**project.json**

```
{

      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.0.1",
          "type": "platform"
        },
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
          "type": "build"
        },
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0"
      },

      "tools": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-prview2-final",
          "imports": [ "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ]
        }
      },

      "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
          "imports": [
            "dotnet5.6",
            "portable-net45+win8"
          ]
        }
      },

      "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true,
        "preserveCompilationContext": true
      },

      "runtimeOptions": {
        "configProperties": {
          "System.GC.Server": true
        }
      },

      "publishOptions": {
        "include": [
          "wwwroot",
          "web.config"
        ]
      },

      "scripts": {
        "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
      }
    }
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Store;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        private IConfigurationRoot _configurationRoot;  

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsetting.json")
                .Build();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                                        options.UseSqlServer(_configurationRoot.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddTransient<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IAlbumRepository, AlbumRepository>();
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Migrate your `project.json` to csproj package referencing with Visual Studio 2017. The version of Entity Framework you're using no longer supports project.json - http://stackoverflow.com/a/43106651/5062791

Comment: If you are using VS 2015 is would not recommend to do what ColinM suggests. Your project will not longer work. The new *.csproj projects only work with VS 2017. Also in your project json in the tools section there is a typo "1.0.0-prview2-final". Maybe this is your problem. Otherwise I suggest you use an older version of the ef tools. `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final"` should work.

Comment: The problem with using an older version of the tool is that you are not keeping up to date with patches and bug fixes, you are then using, or becoming dependent on, a potentially vulnerable package. The new *.csproj do only work in VS 2017, but backward compatibility is always something that has been hit & miss with Visual Studio versions whereas migrating works just fine.

Comment: ```"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0",``` incorrect package version. Change it to 1.0.0-preview2-final for `Add-Migration` syntax. You would also like to upgrade your packages to 1.0.x since there were several patched version released.